# After updating the custom post type, metafields disappear from the post.php edit menu, how do I fix it?

Tags: post-meta, post-editor

Internet does not have a solution for this specific condition. First I create a new post as below:

```
$user_suan = wp_get_current_user();
$args = array(
    'author'        =>  $user_suan->ID, 
    'post_type' => 'CutePostType',
    );
$current_user_posts = get_posts( $args );
if(count($current_user_posts) == 0) {
$my_post = array(
'post_title'   =>   'COOLPOSTNAME', 
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_type'     =>'CutePostType',
  'post_author'   =>$user_suan->ID
);
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
$current_user_posts = get_posts( $args );
$current_user_post = $current_user_posts[0];
update_post_meta( $current_user_post->ID, 'MYLOVELYMETAFIELD', '');
```

After that my lovely meta field appear on the edit screen of post. I can populate it by hand. Save or use its all ok. Untill now there is no problem.

But when I use the code below it just removes my lovely meta field from the post edit screen. But at the frontend(post template), I am able to ask for the metafields of the post and display them correctly with proper unserializations. Problem is, I want to see my lovely meta field on the "post edit" page as a lovely string or etc. (wp-admin/post.php action=edit)

```
$MYLOVELYMETAFIELDVALUE= array('hedge'=>array('sonic'=>'dog','sound'=>'woofwoof'));
update_post_meta( $current_user_post->ID, 'MYLOVELYMETAFIELD', $MYLOVELYMETAFIELDVALUE);
```

How can I make them editable from post edit page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is :
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/managing-post-metadata/#hidden-arrays

Arrays are hidden in default. Please code your own post edit screen.

Thank you myself! This helps another one.